# Angular JS - Re-Render Default Search Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an scenario where I have a set of data being displayed in a table using ng-repeat. This is being filtered by the object "filterArray":

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in data.items | filter:filterParam">
```

There are a selection of dropdown boxes which update the model "filterParam":

```
<ui-select ng-model="filterParam.name" theme="bootstrap" style="width:300px;">
```

This works fine, when I select the option it updates the model and the table updates.

Also, I also have a bar chart which displays the data, and clicking on one of the bars calls a function in the controller:

```
$scope.clicked = function(points, evt) {
    if (points.length > 0) {
        var label = points[0]._model.label;
        $scope.filterParam.name = label;
    }
}
```

When this is clicked, the model object is updated but the data in the table is not updated. Note that the dropdown box even updates and correctly reflects the set value.

I'm not sure what the cause of this is. I've looked online and  can see people saying to use "`$scope.filterParam.$stateful = true;`" but this only applies to custom filters, not sure how to apply this to the default angular filter.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Best guess is chart scope is isolated from the table scope. Hard to help without a [mcve]

Comment: I don't see how it could be an isolated scope, the graph data uses the current scope data. Also, the model in the current scope is definitely updated, as the dropdown box updates to match the clicked label.

Comment: Well we can't see any of it without a [mcve] and all we can do is guess

Comment: I'm having trouble making a plunkr or something similar for this, I'll have another go at it later, for now I'm putting this functionality to the side.